# Remove ids tag from stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [ids](/questions/tagged/ids) tag has different questions attached. It's sometimes attached to questions with html id's and I also found other cases where it was interpreted as Intrusion Detection System. The tag has no wiki.

Comment: if it's a real shortname for 'Intrusion Detection System', we should alias it to the [tag:intrusion-detection] tag, otherwise we just need to remove it.

Comment: Of the 8 FAQ questions tagged, 7 of them refer to some kind of ID, one refers to intrusion detection. I would recommend removing it

Comment: Scrolling through the list of questions, most of them refer to some kind of ID, even if it should mean intrusion detection, it will be used wrongly.

Comment: I (and possibly others) went through the tag. Retagged all the questions that were about intrusion detection. `[ids]` can be nuked, the remaining uses are useless.